# How to restrict Users to see only their databases where has access?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, permissions, users

I need to restrict the list of database for our users in a SQL Instance
In order to move forward this
I revoked the view any database permission to the user desired.
But I figured out that only applies for databases owners so if you have access to a database but noy like db_owner even if for this user you deny "view any database".
Keep listed the database on the instance

I would like to know how I can restrict to the users to only see their databases where are owners and also databases where only have access.

```
USE [MASTER]
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [MYACCOUNT]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to do that, I'm afraid. There are only two special cases where you won't see all databases:

1. You have deny view any database, and now you will only see the databases that you own. As you have already noticed.
2. You login using contained authentication (directly against a user in the database instead of a login). This session is not sandboxed to the database you logged into. Contained authentication imposes restrictions, though, so you need to make sure that you application(s) supports it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable

Comment: Thanks for the clarification